# Ionic __Azure AD Authentication Error: User Cancelled the flow

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ionic3, adal

I am on ionic 3.
I want to get access token for calling the rest API.
Here is my repo https://my-app.visualstudio.com/_apis/projects?api-version=2.0
and Ionic config files is here.
But I am getting an error message after running this code.

```
    //Here is code
    let authContext: AuthenticationContext = this.msAdal.createAuthenticationContext('https://login.windows.net/tenant-id');

    authContext.acquireTokenAsync(
        'https://my-app.visualstudio.com/_apis/projects?api-version=2.0',
        'app_id',
        window.location.origin + '/',
        'email',
        null
    )
        .then((authResponse: AuthenticationResult) => {
            console.log('Token is' , authResponse.accessToken);
            console.log('Token will expire on', authResponse.expiresOn);
        })
        .catch((e: any) => console.log('Authentication failed', e));
}
```

Error message

```
'Authentication failed Error: User cancelled the flow RequestId:679502144 CorrelationId: 9b553979-94a5-482e-b9f8-a91aba56108a
    at fail (CordovaBridge.js:37)
    at Object.callbackFromNative (cordova.js:293)
    at <anonymous>:1:9'}
```